# Appending items to Dictionary with list inside

Tags: c#, .net

How can I append items to Dictionary using list inside?

Here is my code:

```
Dictionary<string, List<double>> listVariables = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
```

And this is the way that I'm appending new values:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
    listVariables["foo" + x].Add(1.1);
}
```

No errors found, but when I start my application, it crashs and I got this:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information the given key was not present in the dictionary`

I can make it works replaceing `listVariables["foo" + x].Add(1.1);` for `listVariables["foo" + x] = new List<double> { 1.1 };`

But this will always replace the first index value, I want append all data in a row of sequency

How can I solve that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the key already exists, if not, you'll need to add it with an empty list:

```cs
for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++) 
{
    var key = "foo" + x;
    if (!listVariables.ContainsKey(key))
        listVariables.Add(key, new List<double>());

    listVariables[key].Add(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the existence of the key first, adding a new list when necessary.

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++)       
{ 
    var key = "foo" + x;
    if (!listVariables.ContainsKey(key))
        listVariables[key] = new List<double>();
    listVariables[key].Add(1.1); 
}
```